# Samsung Gear development: certificate error when "permit to install application"

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm stuck with trying to run my app on my Gear watch.
I created both the author and device-profile certificates, and registered them both to the IDE.

However when I try to allow development in Connection manager, I get a "Certificate not registered" error.

Yet they seem both well registered. I see them both in window-> preferences -> Tizen SDK -> security profile. I also added the device-profile.xml to the /home/developer folder on the gear, as explained [here](https://developer.tizen.org/fr/forums/general-support/gear-2-integrated-app-warning-failed-install-app).

I cleaned the project, tried to regenerate the certificates, rebooted the gear, to no avail.

And If I try to run the app directly, I get a SIGNATURE_INVALID error...

So I'm getting short of ideas. Does anyone have another one ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, because all my tests, my device-profiles file was named "device-profiles (1).xml", and seems the Tizen OS didn't like all special characters.
I renamed it devices-profile.xml, re-registered it to the IDE and copied it again to the watch, and everything works now.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer as this is indeed the problem. You can import with the dialog in Tizen IDE with any name you want, but inside the ~/tizen-wearable-sdk-data/keystore folder the file must be named device-profile.xml.  This is a shortcoming of the signing workflow and should be addressed as most browsers will rename files on download if there are name collisions. I have taken to storing my profiles in separate folders depending on which device I'm testing along with a copy of the author-crt and keystore folder.

Comment: Tizen SDK also do not like special characters in the applications names.

Comment: Can you say what would be the Certificate Password? I didnt get that in my mail. I think I am getting registration failure because of that wrong password...

Comment: The certificate password is chosen by yourself at a previous stage (when you request the certificate if I remember well)